# Language setting of Facebook app on Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am a beginner of Facebook app developer on Android. I have registered an app on Facebook and ran an sample code successfully. The first step when I start the app from my android phone is to sign in with Facebook account (login session). However, all texts of login session are in German. Anyone knows where to change the default language to English?

Thanks in advance!